Why do I get an Error on Symfony Install using Composer
I am running into the following error when creating a new symfony project using the symfony/symfony package on composer:
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information

In PathRepository.php line 163:
                                                                                     
  The 'url' supplied for the path (src/Symfony/Contracts) repository does not exist  
                                                                                     

I cannot appreciate the error message nor fix it. I have no clue where PathRepository.php is and changing versions of Contracts in composer.json is not helpful. Any ideas while this is failing out of the box? Without suggesting a different package or installer (like symfony-cli).
I ran composer create-project symfony/symfony starter-app-symfony and expected:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: xx installs, xx updates, xx removals
xx package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use 'composer suggest' to see details.
Generating optimized autoload files
xx packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the 'composer fund' command to find out more!
No security vulnerability advisories found


Never seen a dot as seperator in packages. Have you tried composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"7.0.*" my_project_directory as stated in Symfony's documentation?

Yeah mate I actually saw that, the typo was made posting this. The error message would have been different if that is the code I ran. I have amended my question, and it still stands. The docs do suggest running with skeleton and then using require to pull in the symfony framework. I did not try it I am aware of it. It takes longer to do the same thing. Why is this way not working?!!

At the very least, you have a typo, as symfony.symfony should be symfony/symfony. Beyond that, the command you're using has not worked since Symfony 4, which requires PHP 7.4 at the latest. If you explicitly want to use those versions (which are both beyond end-of-life), you can force it with:
composer create-project symfony/symfony:4 project_dir

However, since you're starting a new project, it's highly recommended that you use the latest version of Symfony (which is 7) and the latest version of PHP (which is 8.3):
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"7.0.*" project_dir


Thank you Alex -- the typo is irrelevant, sadly, and my error. I will try it as you have suggested with the hopes that it will work for php8. Otherwise, if it is strict to the requirements that you have stated, it will surely break, and fail. But why must it fail? Can I not change anything in the code someplace to force an install completion as much of the symfony scaffolding has been generated? Just breaks at the installation of contracts, which are not one thing but several. Not all too clear how important they are from reading the docs.

"But why must it fail?" Because failing withing changing anything is preferable to leaving the project in a half-done state that is known to not work.

As expected Alex, it fails and it is strict to requiring php7 for symfony4. I also understand you better. I just cannot use that command for the new symfony versions. Which means your response is similar to the comment by @brombeer . That is right, failing is better than leaving a half baked project, but half baked is what it is presently doing. It should fail earlier. Right now, using the first command, i feel the contracts requirement is just pointing to the wrong repo or does not have a repo, so all I have to do is go make the update. That is the response I am looking for.

As I could not find PathRepository.php myself to inspect further what the code is doing or where it is looking for these contracts. It is usually something like that, contracts was added to the project in version 5 but rather than update the core/installer, they switched the process. So, you could fix it if you knew where to put something, once you find the repo on github and its url. Easier than screaming in the issues panel for a two month fix that involves someone spotting your error, alerting a dev, who will also wait for approval of their code change.

But hard as everyone who uses this has to fix it for themselves.

Both your responses are incomplete by the way as you still have to run one more command to bring in the framework, after installing the skeleton... which is weird.

I'm very confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you starting a new project or are you just trying to use some individual components? What version of Symfony are you intending to use?

I am starting a new project. I am more interested in just using symfony, and the latest version is probably best at this stage for a person like myself. I skim read the docs, and skipped over any version specific things. I ran the scaffolding command. And got that error, which just stopped my progress and prompted me to seek help.

"you still have to run one more command to bring in the framework" Not sure what command you're referring to. The create-project command builds your composer.json with all the necessary framework requirements and then automatically installs and configures them. You can start the app immediately after running it.

You ran the wrong command, simple as that. You were following an old tutorial and/or reading old docs. If you're starting a new project, then you should be using Symfony 7 and PHP 8.2+. Run that one command I posted, and that's all you need.

From https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"7.0.*" my_project_directory to start or for API/console app and navigate into project and run composer require webapp for a traditional webapp. Right, APIs and console apps are specialized apps that work in the background of something else. Thanks though, very helpful.
Contracts are here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/contracts.html
